# How to get an element query into json (for vue) without extra data?

Tags: templating, vue

Lets say I want to get a list of category names and ids and pass them into JSON (for vue.js).

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
{% set sections = craft.categories.group('teamCategory').select(['title','elements.id','groupId']).all() %}

<!-- My vue.js tag: -->
<team :sections="{{ sections|json_encode() }}"></team>
```

My problem is that I only want `title` and `id` to be passed to vue, but craft/twig is passing load and loads more data that forms part of the category object.

Is there an easy way to just pass the array columns I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `asArray` function to return arrays instead of elements

```twig
{% set sections = craft
    .categories
    .group('teamCategory')
    .select(['title','elements.id','groupId'])
    .asArray()
    .all() 
%}
```

Comment: Nice. That's the ticket. I wonder why this approach never stood out for me. Maybe I need to go and read the docs again!